# How to use a flag with two different names (short and long)

Tags: go, flags, go-cobra

I am using https://github.com/spf13/cobra to work with flags.

I want my CLI to have flag with two names:  `-t` or `--token`.

I currently used it like that:

```
rootCmd.PersistentFlags().String("token", "", "Token to insert")
```

But it prints me the flags like that:

```
Flags:

      -h, --help           help for myapp
          --token string   Token to insert
```

I want it to be like that:

```
Flags:

      -h, --help           help for myapp
      -t, --token string   Token to insert
```

How can I do it?
I didn't find it on google, I tried to search for multiple names for a flag but without success.

Comment: It's in the examples in the readme at the page you linked: https://github.com/spf13/cobra#working-with-flags so e.g. use `StringVarP` in place of `StringVar` or `StringP` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is an example in the documentation.  This example uses both `--projectbase` and `-b`:

```
rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&projectBase, "projectbase", "b", "", "base project directory eg. github.com/spf13/")
```